# Meaning of "as I hope to be caressed"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I'm working with a 17th century text which often features the expression "as I hope to be caressed".

My idea is that it is a second term of comparison, with ironic meaning, to something that will never (or hardly) happen.

example (mine): "I hope I'll break free from this prison, as I hope to be caressed"  = it is unlikely I will break free, as it is unlikely I will be caressed (treated well) by someone

Am I right? Do you have better explanations?

Comment: Why not "I hope for this lonely imprisonment to end because I want to be held lovingly"?

Comment: This might mean "I hope for X because I hope for Y", but is more likely in 17th-century diction to mean "I hope for X in the same degree as I hope for Y". Can you supply more actual context? --without that it's impossible to say whether it is meant ironically or naively.

Comment: You'd have to supply LONGER quotes, and more than one.

Comment: Impossible to say from a single example.  Much more text would be required to tell if the writer is being ironic or not.

Comment: Actually, I made up my own phrase because in-text quotations are brief and quite unclear. That's the best I found, it's a dialogue between two characters:

" - This show you to be an ill-designing Person.
- Ha, ha, ha, very merry, as I hope to be caress'd."     

Hope it helps.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, I went for the ironic interpretation because the expression belongs to a character who is badly treated and offended by others.

Comment: I'm sure I remember seeing the expression 'as I hope to be saved' in older literature, though Googling it finds nothing. It would be used as an intensifier, as StoneyB says: "I hope for X as earnestly as I hope to be saved (in the religious sense)." Maybe "as I hope to be caressed" is a flippant variant of this?

Comment: @KateBunting I think this is exactly right -- it's a play on "as I hope to be **blessed**".

Comment: @Farquhar I think Beau Gentle is far too shallow to be capable of irony.

Comment: By the way, this an 18th-century text.

Comment: @StoneyB indeed, it was a typo. Many thanks for your comments and your detailed reply below -- I think your explanation is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Kate Bunting: I think that *as I hope to be caressed* is a jocular minced oath, standing for *as I hope to be **blessed***.

Both times Beau Gentle uses the phrase he does so to re-assert his immediately preceding phrase:

- Gentle is rebuked by the Emperor of the Mohocks for speaking (as the Emperor feigns to believe) Latin to a peace officer; Gentle responds by mocking the Emperor’s ignorance.

  > *Gent*. Ha, ha, ha, very merry, as I hope to be careſs’d. *Latin* and *French* ſound alike in the Ears of the vulgar.
- Gentle has been tied back-to-back with Joan and objects in terms which give offense to Joan; he hastens to qualify his expression as merely figurative:

  > *Gent*. I beg you, Gentlemen; this Posture is ſo like Man and Wife, that a Man of Mode may be perfectly aſhamed of it. [...] careſs’d.
  >   *Joan*. Go you *Hawkubite* Rogue, you ungracious Wretch!
  >   *Gent.* Figurative Matrimony, as I hope to be careſs’d; one pulls one way, and the other the other.

The 16th-18th century had many tags which might be used here—*as I hope to be saved*, *as God is my witness*, *as I am an honest man*, *as I live and breathe*, and so forth. They are all used to assert the truth of what is said. Pious versions rest the contingency expressed in the tag (e.g., the speaker’s salvation) on the speaker’s veracity; mundane versions represent the speaker’s utterance as just as true as the self-evident assertion in the tag (*everybody* wants to be caressed).

I imagine the phrase is put into Gentle’s mouth to demonstrate his frivolous character and dedication to such genteel pleasures as ombre and rococo erotics.